# Animate CC: How to access root stage when button is clicked

Tags: html5-canvas, animate-cc

Firstly, I create Canvas Project with Adobe Animate CC. But I have a problem with action code.

I have 2 symbols on stage. How can I get access the symbol on main movie clip?

```
var _this = this;

_this.Text.on('click', function(){

_this.gotoAndPlay('sym2');
});
```

I need to edit this code to access symbol on main movie clip:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9em62bbifwaxqv4/test2.fla?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a scoping issue. In test2.fla, your object named Text is contained with an object named TradeMarks.

The code in your clip read:

```
_this.Text.on('click', function(){
    _this.parent.sym2.gotoAndPlay(3);
});
```

Whereas that would look for an object named "sym2" on TradeMarks, not at the root timeline.

I think you will get what you want by changing it to read:

```
_this.Text.on('click', function(){
    _this.parent.parent.sym2.gotoAndPlay(3);
});
```